# New controls not showing up in Intellisense

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have a winform in VS2013 writing in c#. I adjusted two group boxes, and now new controls added to the form don't show up in Intellisense.

There are a number of questions that are similar, but i can't find one that applies, so forgive me if this is or seems to be a repeat (and I am a relative newbie coder).

One post indicated this error may occur if there is an error in the layout that can't be solved. I don't see one, and nothing i see indicates an error, tho this may be correct because i believe the problem occurred after changing the layout.

Things I have tried:
1)Closing everything, restarting the computer
2)CLean Solution
3)Switch to Release mode, compile, then back to Debug mode

THere are answers relating to the aspx designer file, but that seems to be in a different environment.

THanks!

Answer (score 0):

(1) upgrade to [vs2015](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691978&clcid=0x409)

*If that doesn't work,*

(2) compress the whole solution [code and everything], preferably to zip or rar, and add a link to download it from a website such as [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/), etc.

Comment: hmmm...trying to figure out how to "add a link".

Comment: @DanG go to https://mega.nz/ and make an account and upload the file, then get a download link for it

Comment: here's the Solution: https://mega.nz/#!x8hUkRRA!LaXWvdBt1q3u3JQ0KYmw6WfiR6zMgsiut_x_Uncr-Rs

Comment: here's the whole folder: https://mega.nz/#!x8hUkRRA!LaXWvdBt1q3u3JQ0KYmw6WfiR6zMgsiut_x_Uncr-Rs

Comment: @DanG right there you only uploaded the sln file, can you upload the whole project?